# create object using variables for property name

Tags: javascript, properties, object-literal

Is it at all possible to use variable names in object literal properties for object creation?

Example

```
function createJSON (propertyName){
    return { propertyName : "Value"};
}

var myObject = createJSON("myProperty");

console.log(myObject.propertyName);  // Prints "value"
console.log(myObject.myProperty);  // This property does not exist
```

Answer (score 248, accepted):

If you want to use a variable for a property name, you can use [Computed Property Names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015). Place the variable name between square brackets:

```
var foo = "bar";
var ob  = { [foo]: "something" }; // ob.bar === "something"
```

If you want Internet Explorer support you will need to use the ES5 approach (which you could get by writing modern syntax (as above) and then applying [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)):

Create the object first, and then add the property using [square bracket notation](http://www.dev-archive.net/articles/js-dot-notation/).

```
var foo = "bar";
var ob  = {};
ob[foo] = "something"; // === ob.bar = "something"
```

If you wanted to programatically create JSON, you would have to serialize the object to a string conforming to the JSON format. e.g. with [the `JSON.stringify` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Answer (score 51):

ES6 introduces computed property names, which allow you to do

```
function CreateJSON (propertyName){
    var myObject = { [propertyName] : "Value"};
}
```

Note browser support is currently negligible.

Comment: interesting, any updates on browser support?

Comment: When I wrote the answer, only Firefox Nigthly. Now Firefox 34+ and Safari 7.1.3+, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: This is the best answer for me. I'm using nodejs.

Comment: As of 2020, all browsers now support computed property names except for IE.

Answer (score 10):

You can sort of do this:

```
  var myObject = {};
  CreateProp("myProperty","MyValue");

  function CreateProp(propertyName, propertyValue)
  {
      myObject[propertyName] = propertyValue;
      alert(myObject[propertyName]);  // prints "MyValue" 
  };
```

I much perfer this syntax myself though:

```
function jsonObject()
{
};
var myNoteObject = new jsonObject();

function SaveJsonObject()
{
    myNoteObject.Control = new jsonObject();
    myNoteObject.Control.Field1= "Fred";
    myNoteObject.Control.Field2= "Wilma";
    myNoteObject.Control.Field3= "Flintstone";
    myNoteObject.Control.Id= "1234";
    myNoteObject.Other= new jsonObject();
    myNoteObject.Other.One="myone";
};
```

Then you can use the following:

```
SaveJsonObject();
var myNoteJSON = JSON.stringify(myNoteObject);
```

NOTE: This makes use of the json2.js from here:http://www.json.org/js.html

Answer (score 6):

One thing that may be suitable (now that JSON functionality is common to newer browsers, and json2.js is a perfectly valid fallback), is to construct a JSON string and then parse it.

```
function func(prop, val) {
    var jsonStr = '{"'+prop+'":'+val+'}';
    return JSON.parse(jsonStr);
}

var testa = func("init", 1);
console.log(testa.init);//1
```

Just keep in mind, JSON property names need to be enclosed in double quotes.