# Create object property from variable contents

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I have this simple object.

```
var myobj = {
   id: value
}
```

But instead of having a property named "id" I want the property identifier to be the value of:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

I cannot preset this as I do not know the ID of the element. I want to be able to get my property value by

```
<id-of-element>.id
```

I understand I cannot do like this:

```
var myobj = {
   $(this).attr('id'): value
}
```

but how can I solve it? :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [create object using variables for property name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153969/create-object-using-variables-for-property-name)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't assign a dynamic property name like that, but you can use the `[]` notation:

```
var myobj = {};
myobj[$(this).attr('id')] = value;
```

- [MDN Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) is a good resource covering this method.

Comment: So simple, so awesome, so quick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ES6 introduces computed property names, which allow you to do

```
var myobj = {
   [$(this).attr('id')]: value
}
```

Note browser support is currently negligible.